# Http digest authentication with Mule 3.7

Tags: http, spring-security, mule, mule-esb

I would like to do Http digest authentication for a http inbound endpoint in mule 3.7. I am able to use the spring authentication provider to perform basic authentication as per the mule examples provided. But i could not find any documentation as to how digest authentication can be done the same way. Could someone help. This is what i have tried till now.
This example with basic authentication works for me:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/configuring-the-spring-security-manager

I am looking to implement this:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-digest-authentication

Thanks,
Jean

Comment: Did you got this resolved?

Comment: No. It’s not resolved yet.